# A* Algorithm Search

Tags: algorithm, tree, path-finding

I have a tree like the one below. Numbers on the edges are costs (g) and number in the nodes are the estimated distance from the goal from the heuristic function (h). The goal is shaded in grey.

[image]

If I start at S, the route, would the traversal for A-star search (`f(x) = g(x) + h(x)`) be as follow: `S>B>H>M` ?

This is a funny question because if we are looking instead at the Greedy search algo where the function for determining the next move = `f(x) = h(x)` we will consider the values in the nodes only and select the least one. Based on this we will start at S and then go on to A (lowest value best), but the leftmost branch is incorrect as it will not lead to any of the goal nodes. Would I be correct to assume that a greedy search will fail with this tree?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, this is not a tree, it's a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), because some nodes have multiple parents.

Secondly, yes, A* will return the correct result with this heuristic, because the heuristic is [admissible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic) *(ie. it never overestimates the true cost)*.  If that were not true, A* might not return the correct result.

Comment: +1 for this correct answer, for using the correct terminology and for pointing out the required condition for A* on a tree/DAG. The other answer is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

No, the greedy search will walk through S->A->D->B->F. 
Heuristic search is just try to speed up the search but it won't make the search fail, the worst case is just it takes longer time than no heuristic.

Comment: -1 This answer is incorrect. A* search will not always return the optimal result - the heuristic has to be consistent (that is, hold the triangle equality `heuristic(current,Goal) <= cost(current,someOtherNode) + heuristic(thatNode,Goal)`. However like the other answer points out in this specific case Admissability is enough. Moreover - Greedy best first search, unlike A* is not guaranteed to return an optimal solution _anyway_.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Actually, admissibility is always the correctness-criterion for A\*.  Having a consistent heuristic is nice though, because it allows us to speed up the algorithm  *(specifically, we can guarantee any node in the closed list was reached optimally, so it will never have to be re-queued to the open-list.  This is not true of non-consistent heuristics)*

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft not on a graph it's not. On a graph, it's quite possible to have an admissible heuristic that's not consistent. Simple example out of my head: G = (V,E) is a weighted directed graph. V = (S=start,B,G=Goal). E = (S,B) cost 2000, (B,G) cost 1000, (A,G) cost 2200. Let's define a heuristic H, H(S) = 2100, H(B) = 50, H(G) = 0. H is clearly admissible by definition (all heuristic costs are less than the actual distance) , however the solution found by A* here: S->B->G costs 3000 while the optimal solution A->G costs 2200.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: That's incorrect, A\* finds the correct path in that example.  After opening `B`, the algorithm will notice that `G` is already in the open-list, so will compare `f(B --> G)` with `f(S --> G)`, and notice that it will result in a higher cost.  Thus, when `G` is finally dequeued, its parent will still be `S`.  If you'd like to discuss this further, please ask a new question about A\* and admissibility [on the CS site](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) and link me to it from here.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Sorry, forgot to ping. Here's a repost: That's what I get for making numbers up in the comments nad building graphs in my head :) Anyway, here's a short example of an admissable but not consistent heuristic returning an incorrect result in A* http://i.imgur.com/iQkb21e.png

Comment: @Benjamin:  A\* will **provably** always find the optimal solution with an admissible heuristic, on any graph.  In your image above, the `A` node will need to be re-added to the open-list after it is closed the first time; as I mentioned, this is possible for non-consistent heuristics.  When it is closed the second time, it will have the correct parent.  If you have more questions, please ask them at the site I linked above.

Comment: You didn't really understand the problem, in this problem greedy search is guaranteed to find the goal, worst case is just find the goal after walk through every node.